# Use class to bind three cascading DDLs

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I am trying my best to make my web application faster as much as I can, one of the options I am looking is reducing the codes into each page. So i have three DDLs as mention below they do the same job to bind the DDLs depending on cookie value. So how I can create a class and use it to bind all DDLs

-StateHPDDL

-BizstateHPFilterDDL

-filterstathpjob

the code used for each DDL in page_load is as below

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (cookie["Location"] == null)
            {

                DataTable filterstathpAdsDT = new DataTable();

                using (SqlConnection filterstathpAdsCon = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {

                    SqlCommand filterstathpAdsCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT State FROM State WHERE Country = @Location", filterstathpAdsCon);

                    var Location = cookie.Value;

                    filterstathpAdsCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location);


                    SqlDataAdapter filterstathpAdsAP = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    filterstathpAdsAP.SelectCommand = filterstathpAdsCMD;
                    filterstathpAdsAP.Fill(filterstathpAdsDT);

                    StateHPDDL.DataSource = filterstathpAdsDT;
                    StateHPDDL.DataTextField = "State";

                    StateHPDDL.DataBind();
                }

                StateHPDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Province", ""));
            }


        }
```

Please i will appreciate if you explain step by step that make make it more clear for me to understand and follow your steps

Answer (score 0):

i has solved in easy way as below and its works fine

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (cookie["Location"] == null)
            {

                DataTable filterstathpBizDT = new DataTable();

                using (SqlConnection filterstathpBizCon = new SqlConnection(cs))
                {

                    SqlCommand filterstathpBizCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT State FROM State WHERE Country = @Location", filterstathpBizCon);

                    var Location = cookie.Value;

                    filterstathpBizCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", Location);


                    SqlDataAdapter filterstathpBizAP = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    filterstathpBizAP.SelectCommand = filterstathpBizCMD;
                    filterstathpBizAP.Fill(filterstathpBizDT);

                    BizstateHPFilterDDL.DataSource = filterstathpBizDT;
                    StateHPDDL.DataSource = filterstathpBizDT;
                    filterstathpjob.DataSource = filterstathpBizDT;

                    BizstateHPFilterDDL.DataTextField = "State";
                    StateHPDDL.DataTextField = "State";
                    filterstathpjob.DataTextField = "State";

                    BizstateHPFilterDDL.DataBind();
                    StateHPDDL.DataBind();
                    filterstathpjob.DataBind();
                }

                BizstateHPFilterDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Province", ""));
                StateHPDDL.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Province", ""));
                filterstathpjob.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Province", ""));
            }


        }
```